# Help in peer-to-peer wifi

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I ask help to you experienced.
I should realize an application for the university that allows the connection among two or more terminal Android in way wifi.
This thing obviously asks for a connection peer-to-peer in how much the terminals must be able to converse among them without using access-point or other.  It's possible as thing?
Have I read the existence of the technology "wifi direct" but have not I found further information on it, the libraries, sdk, or a guide it is available?
Thanks to whom will give me useful info

Comment: You can create an ad-hoc network between the WiFi devices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need to connect on the same SSID. Google "wifi ad hoc network."

Comment: excuse me I have not made sense of well.  I must make to connect two or more phone between them.
The connection must happen ah hoc from phone to phone